# Cucumber + DBUnit (ruby)

Tags: ruby, cucumber, dbunit, calabash

Has anyone ever done the Cucumber + DBUnit setup for ruby ? (I am particularly trying to use it with Calabash for mobile app testing.)

Ideally it sounds like I should be able to add an @Before hook in Cucumber, so that I could there load the test data that I want into the database, before I proceed with the tests. Otherwise it seems to me that I have no way to do data-driven testing.

Note: I do know about Scenario outlines, but I am not (only) looking to run my test with different parameters - rather, I need to bring my database in a known state before I run my tests.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered giving [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) a shot? You can setup database_cleaner so that it cleans your database before each test or whole test suite. It also works nicely [with Cucumber](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner#cucumber-example).

Comment: Thanks very much Oto! (had completely missed your reply, so apologies for the delay) 
This basically solves half my problem - I can use this to truncate some tables (which is nice! and I do need this) but what I also need and couldn't find was how to pre-load the database with an 'initial state', the same way you can do with DbUnit... Any ideas on that?

Comment: Preloading database can be done with fixtures, factories or seeds. Fixtures and seeds are static files (YAML) that are read when you run your test-suite and they populate your database with initial data. Factories are a bit more advance, they can build not just database records but whole "objects", object that can vary in behaviour or data. If your data is simple check fixtures, otherwise go with factories.

You will have to provide more information about your database/project if you want more accurate answer... How complex is your initial database state?

Comment: Thanks again Oto!
Thanks for pointing out the differences between them. Are fixtures mainly for Rails apps? I presume I'll be able to use them in a plain ruby project (i.e. without rails - it's a calabash-ios project), I just need to work out how...

Comment: Ok - I admit it - I gave up on the 'proper' way to do this.. I didn't really have the time to learn ruby, so I ended up just creating a tag that I've added to some of my Calabash tests, and that uses a system() command to restore the mysql database from a file backup. 
I know it's not great, but it's good enough for now...  : /

Comment: C'mon. Its not that bad. yes you can use fixtures, without Rails just in Ruby. Usually you pick ActiveRecord or DataMapper that has all this sweet things already build so that you don't reinvent the wheel. However more I read your question more I get the feeling that this calabash-ios might not be the thing that you actually need. Have you considered using something more native. Something like XCTest, Spectra (https://github.com/specta/specta) or KIF (https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF)?

Comment: :) yeah well, the ruby learning curve was a bit of an overkill for my project... 
In terms of the testing framework, no, I do *not* want to use something more native, because one of the great advantages of calabash is that it's both Android, as well as iOS compatible.. Talk about reinventing the wheel when I'd have to write my tests twice for the same app on 2 platforms... ;)
Thanks again though! Appreciate all your help!